# Bitlocker HDD does not show on BIOS, but can be mounted in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, bitlocker

I ran defraggler on my secondary HDD that has software bitlocker on. Defraggler froze and I did the stupid thing of killing it. After a reboot the driver didn't show up on Windows 10. I rebooted again and it showed up, next day I turn on the computer and it is now gone again and not coming back. It does not show on Disk Management or Device Manager anymore. I downloaded Ubuntu and live boot it, I was able to mount the bitlocker and do a new backup of everything.

I tried searching for a solution to get the driver to show up again on BIOS (UEFI) and Windows, with no lucky.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the drive itself is dying - did you check its SMART data?

Comment: I went to BIOS to boot pick the live ubuntu usb stick and the HDD was there again. I boot to Windows instead and the HDD show up again. I didn't do any anything special. The SMART attributes for that HDD are all set to "GOOD".